# How to edit header labels and convert data rows to columns in batch file?

Tags: windows, csv, for-loop, batch-file

I have a CSV file with a single header record and field data as:

```
region,travelnum,seatnum,1.Stat.Money.Min,1.Stat.Money.Avg,1.Stat.Money.Med,1.Stat.Money.Max,1.Stat.Money.Std,1.Stat.Family.Min,1.Stat.Family.Avg,1.Stat.Family.Med,1.Stat.Family.Max,1.Stat.Family.Std,1.Stat.Travel.Min,1.Stat.Travel.Avg,1.Stat.Travel.Med,1.Stat.Travel.Max,1.Stat.Travel.Std,1.Stat.Job.Min,1.Stat.Job.Avg,1.Stat.Job.Med,1.Stat.Job.Max,1.Stat.Job.Std
A and B,324,8714,0.48,(...),
C and D,199,1733,0.32,(...),
E and F,915,2501,0.72,(...),
...
```

Number '1' corresponds to the 'name' of the subject, in which each subject has its own folder with this .csv file. For the subject 2, the header changes 1 to 2. The idea is to rearrange the .csv with a lot of rows into one row for the header and the other row for the values but a lot of columns. For an easier dataframe...

What should be:

```
name,A_and_B_travelnum,A_and_B_seatnum,A_and_B_Money_Min,A_and_B_Money_Avg,A_and_B_Money_Med,A_and_B_Money_Max,A_and_B_Money_Std,A_and_B_Family_Min,A_and_B_Family_Avg,A_and_B_Family_Med,A_and_B_Family_Max,A_and_B_Family_Std,A_and_B_Travel_Min,A_and_B_Travel_Avg,A_and_B_Travel_Med,A_and_B_Travel_Max,A_and_B_Travel_Std,A_and_B_Job_Min,A_and_B_Job_Avg,A_and_B_Job_Med,A_and_B_Job_Max,A_and_B_Job_Std,C_and_D_travelnum,C_and_D_seatnum,C_and_D_Money_Min,C_and_D_Money_Avg,C_and_D_Money_Med,C_and_D_Money_Max,C_and_D_Money_Std,C_and_D_Family_Min,C_and_D_Family_Avg,C_and_D_Family_Med,C_and_D_Family_Max,C_and_D_Family_Std,C_and_D_Travel_Min,C_and_D_Travel_Avg,C_and_D_Travel_Med,C_and_D_Travel_Max,C_and_D_Travel_Std,C_and_D_Job_Min,C_and_D_Job_Avg,C_and_D_Job_Med,C_and_D_Job_Max,C_and_D_Job_Std,...
1,324,8714,0.48,(...),199,1733,0.32,(...),...
```

What I did:

```bash
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

set "region[A and B]=A_and_B"
set "region[C and D]=C_and_D"
set "region[E and F]=E_and_F"

set "metric[.Stat.Money.Min]=Money_Min"
set "metric[.Stat.Money.Avg]=Money_Avg"
set "metric[.Stat.Money.Med]=Money_Med"
set "metric[.Stat.Money.Max]=Money_Max"
set "metric[.Stat.Money.Std]=Money_Std"

set "metric[.Stat.Family.Min]=Family_Min"
set "metric[.Stat.Family.Avg]=Family_Avg"
set "metric[.Stat.Family.Med]=Family_Med"
set "metric[.Stat.Family.Max]=Family_Max"
set "metric[.Stat.Family.Std]=Family_Std"

set "metric[.Stat.Travel.Min]=Travel_Min"
set "metric[.Stat.Travel.Avg]=Travel_Avg"
set "metric[.Stat.Travel.Med]=Travel_Med"
set "metric[.Stat.Travel.Max]=Travel_Max"
set "metric[.Stat.Travel.Std]=Travel_Std"

set "metric[.Stat.Job.Min]=Job_Min"
set "metric[.Stat.Job.Avg]=Job_Avg"
set "metric[.Stat.Job.Med]=Job_Med"
set "metric[.Stat.Job.Max]=Job_Max"
set "metric[.Stat.Job.Std]=Job_Std"

for /d %%y in (*) do (
    set id=%%y
    rem set nameDIR=%parentfolder%\!name!
    call :identification
)

goto EOF:

:identification
set /p "file=" < "!id!\name.csv"
> !id!\name.csv (
   for /f "skip=0 tokens=* delims=," %%x in ("!id!\name.csv")
       echo name,!region[A and B]!_travelnum,!region[A and B]!_seatnum,!region[A and B]!!metric[.Stat.Money.Min]!...
   for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ("!id!\name.csv") do (
       echo !id!,%%a,%%a,%%a,...
   )
)
```

I don't know how to concatenate the other values in the second row inside the for loop.

See the following example:
[To clarify the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYtN9.png)

Comment: My first thought is where is the benefit in creating variables with names which are significantly more characters, and less understandable that the actual strings they are representing? Also ```goto EOF:``` should be ```GoTo :EOF```. And why define `id`? when you could just ```Call :identification %%y```, then use `%1` instead of `!id!`. Also your first  `for` loop under `:identification` is missing `do`!

Comment: If you see, the rows that has the regions should stay in the column for each parameter (min, avg, med, max, std). I didn't understand your point mate.

Comment: It's much simpler to use the string `Job_Min` than to use `!metric[.Stat.Job.Min]!`, (there's sixteen less characters to type)!

Comment: Do any of your columns contain quoted strings that potentially contain commas?

Comment: Is PowerShell an option? You could easily do that with Import-Csv / Export-Csv

Comment: @UncleCisco: I am tired of read this type of _opinions_... If you could easily do this in PowerShel, why you just didn't write it and post it here? Such a solution will be much shorter than my Batch answer below for sure, isn't it?

Comment: I've already done a lot in batch to execute my necessity, I've never used powershell and I do not have time to learn it at this moment. But Thank for the advise @UncleCisco.

Comment: @Compo I could type all the labels on the header of the CSV but I thought that could be a faster way like this (with for loop).

Comment: @Magoo the header won't have commas in the labels, only those that separate the values or strings. From the second line, in the first column, I want to join the label from the second string (second column) respectively. Instead of each row will have its columns. The result will be only one header (with the label of the region for each parameter) and the second row only the numbered values.

Comment: @ÍtaloCésarPortoXavier, even if that were true, you'd use: `Set "FMn=Family_Min"`, `Set "FAg=Family_Avg"`, `Set "FMd=Family_Med"`, `Set "FMx=Family_Max"`, `Set "FSd=Family_Std"`, `Set "TMn=Travel_Min"`, `Set "TAg=Travel_Avg"`, `Set "TMd=Travel_Med"`, `Set "TMx=Travel_Max"`, `Set "TSd=Travel_Std"`, `Set "JMn=Job_Min"`, `Set "JAg=Job_Avg"`, `Set "JMd=Job_Med"`, `Set "JMx=Job_Max"`, `Set "JSd=Job_Std"`.
Whilst we don't expect thanks, ignoring the fixes for the invalid code you submitted, and advice to streamline and improve your code, is not a good trait for this type of community.

Comment: Also, please do not post images like that, in your question body. There is no reason whay that cannot be copied from the text editor, and pasted directly into your question, and formatted as code to maintain its structure.

Comment: @Aacini chill dude, I asked because PowerShell sometimes is not an option. Corporate environments not always allow PS scripts. The reason I didn't gave an answer right the way is because I don't have the knowledge to do it in batch ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @UncleCisco: Forget mention Batch... You said: _"You could **easily** do that with PowerShell"_. I just said: _"Prove it"_. If you can't, then IMHO you shouldn't do such a type of comments about PS that could confuse the beginners... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini. Sorry dude, won't happen again : )
# Same properties in header.
Import-Csv -Path C:\Path\To\My\Super\Csv.csv | Export-Excel -Path C:\Output\File.xlsx
# Custom properties names.
$customHeaderObject = @(); Import-Csv -Path C:\Path\To\My\Super\Csv.csv | % { $customHeaderObject += [PSCustomObject]@{ NewName = $_.OldProperty } }; $customHeaderObject | Export-Excel -Path C:\Output\File.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty confusing. You should explain it more clearly and include more input and output example data... Anyway, this is my version of what *I think* you requested:

**EDIT:** *Code modified as requested in comment*

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set "name[A and B]=1"
set "name[C and D]=2"
set "name[E and F]=3"

set "reg[1]=A_and_B"
set "reg[2]=C_and_D"
set "reg[3]=E_and_F"

for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%a in (name.csv) do (
   set "header=,!reg[#n#]!_%%b,!reg[#n#]!_%%c,%%d"
   goto break
)
:break
set "header=%header:1.Stat=!reg[#n#]!%"
set "header=%header:.=_%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "header=!header:#n#=%%n!"

del result.txt body.txt 2>NUL
set "name=name"
set "comma=1,"

< NUL (
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (name.csv) do (
   for %%n in (!name[%%a]!) do (
      set /P "=!name!%header%" >> result.txt
      set /P "=!comma!%%b" >> body.txt
   )
   set "name="
   set "comma=,"
)
) 

echo/>> result.txt
echo/>> body.txt
type body.txt >> result.txt
type result.txt
```

Output:

```
name,A_and_B_travelnum,A_and_B_seatnum,A_and_B_Money_Min,A_and_B_Money_Avg,A_and_B_Money_Med,A_and_B_Money_Max,A_and_B_Money_Std,A_and_B_Family_Min,A_and_B_Family_Avg,A_and_B_Family_Med,A_and_B_Family_Max,A_and_B_Family_Std,A_and_B_Travel_Min,A_and_B_Travel_Avg,A_and_B_Travel_Med,A_and_B_Travel_Max,A_and_B_Travel_Std,A_and_B_Job_Min,A_and_B_Job_Avg,A_and_B_Job_Med,A_and_B_Job_Max,A_and_B_Job_Std,C_and_D_travelnum,C_and_D_seatnum,C_and_D_Money_Min,C_and_D_Money_Avg,C_and_D_Money_Med,C_and_D_Money_Max,C_and_D_Money_Std,C_and_D_Family_Min,C_and_D_Family_Avg,C_and_D_Family_Med,C_and_D_Family_Max,C_and_D_Family_Std,C_and_D_Travel_Min,C_and_D_Travel_Avg,C_and_D_Travel_Med,C_and_D_Travel_Max,C_and_D_Travel_Std,C_and_D_Job_Min,C_and_D_Job_Avg,C_and_D_Job_Med,C_and_D_Job_Max,C_and_D_Job_Std,E_and_F_travelnum,E_and_F_seatnum,E_and_F_Money_Min,E_and_F_Money_Avg,E_and_F_Money_Med,E_and_F_Money_Max,E_and_F_Money_Std,E_and_F_Family_Min,E_and_F_Family_Avg,E_and_F_Family_Med,E_and_F_Family_Max,E_and_F_Family_Std,E_and_F_Travel_Min,E_and_F_Travel_Avg,E_and_F_Travel_Med,E_and_F_Travel_Max,E_and_F_Travel_Std,E_and_F_Job_Min,E_and_F_Job_Avg,E_and_F_Job_Med,E_and_F_Job_Max,E_and_F_Job_Std
1,324,8714,0.48,(...),199,1733,0.32,(...),915,2501,0.72,(...)
```

Comment: I have posted the image in the post, see if it helps

Comment: It worked a bit here but it created empty columns with values 1, 2, 3, etc between the blocks of values (on second row). Another thing it's repeating the column labeled 'name', the 'name' is only the first column. In these repetitions, the values are out of order for its corresponding columns. For example, the value of the travelnum is on the previous column labeled 'name_1' as I mentioned before.

Comment: Well, your question clearly specify: _"Number '1' corresponds to the 'name' of the subject... For the subject 2, the header changes 1 to 2."_ You should specified instead: _"For the subject 2 and higher, the header does **not** include the 'name' anymore."_ Check my **EDIT**. If the output is not the desired one please _describe_ the problem and the change needed to get the right output; _don't_ just show an image of what you want... **`:(`**

Comment: Each subject has its own folder. Inside the folder we have the csv file for the subject (for the subject 1 will have 1.csv, for the subject 2 will have 2.csv...). The csv file contains the first column with the regions, but I want to transpose the rows (of the regions not the header) into the columns with each parameter (from the second columns). As the first column will no longer have the regions, I'd like to change the header for the identification of the subject, resulting for example the header name and the following row the subject 1, or ID in the header.  It helps @Aacini?

Comment: As I tried your code here, the result has fewer values in the second row. The body.txt that you created has the exactly number of columns, I mean it's ok, but when appended to result.txt the columns decreased. So resulted in columns at the end with no values. I tried here instead of .txt to .csv do you think this conversion is the problem?

Comment: To minimize the problem I fixed the header as I want with echo, but what I want is to transpose the following rows into the right columns in sequence. If you know how to do that will help me

Comment: Sorry, but your descriptions are pretty confusing... **`:(`** If you have several files with a significant data that changes from one file to another one, I suggest you to _post_ 3 or 4 different files and the desired output in each one of such 3 or 4 files. I can't follow you based only in your description.

Comment: I wrote a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75892610/how-to-correctly-edit-and-organize-a-csv-file-for-a-better-analysis